# how to add draggable "add image" icon in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am curious to know how to add `add image` icon using jquery as in stack overflow. When user clicks it, it increases its size and goes wherever user places it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            #draggable { width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 0.5em; }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                 $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
            <image src="/addImage" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I have added simple image on which user should able to place where he wants to place image. I don't know how to increase the size of that div after dragging. Also I want to get the position where user have added it.

I also want it should ask to browse on pc to upload a image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will increase the size of the draggable after it is been dragged and will return the position (as offset) of the draggable-element:

```
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        stop: function( event, ui ) {         
            ui.helper.css({
                width: '200px',
                height: '200px'
            });
            $('#position').text('Top: ' + ui.position.top + ' Left: ' + ui.position.left)
        }
    });
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m0stytae/)

**Reference**

[.draggable()](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop)

Comment: it's working perfectly but i want it should ask to upload image from client pc and browse